# How to create a script to export all products images in csv programmatically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, export, script

Magento2 how to developed custom script export for list of all product images with associated sku, Alt-Text, Image path,Image size please if anyone creates the script to share with me as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to export csv, using script and another way is using sql queries

This is using Script with Magento

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State')->setAreaCode('frontend');
$fileFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory');
$csvProcessor = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\File\Csv');
$directoryList = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();

$content[] = ['sku' => __('Sku'),
'label' => __('Alt Text'),
'value' => __('Image Path'),
'image-width' => __('Image Width'),
'image-height' => __('Image Height'),];

$fileName = 'product_export.csv'; // Add Your CSV File name
$filePath = $directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::MEDIA) . "/" . $fileName;

foreach ($collection as $product){
    // print_r($product->getData());
    // die;
    //echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName().'<br>';
    $productFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory')->create()->load($product->getId());
    $productImages = $productFactory->getMediaGalleryImages();
    $label = '';
    foreach ($productImages as $image) {
        $label = $image->getLabel();
    }
    
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("pub/media/catalog/product/".$product->getImage());

    $content[] = [$product->getSku(),
        $label,
        $product->getImage(),
        $width,
        $height,];
        //print_r( $product->getImage()); die;
} 

$csvProcessor->setEnclosure('"')->setDelimiter(',')->saveData($filePath, $content);
$fileFactory->create($fileName, ['type' => "filename",
    'value' => $fileName,
    'rm' => true,
    // True => File will be remove from directory after download.
], DirectoryList::MEDIA, 'text/csv', null);
```

And this is another way where we are using sql queries

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State')->setAreaCode('frontend');
$fileFactory = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory');
$csvProcessor = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\File\Csv');
$directoryList = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();

//Select Data from table
$sql = "SELECT catalog_product_entity.sku, catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value.value_id, catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value.label, catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.value FROM `catalog_product_entity` LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value ON catalog_product_entity.entity_id=catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value.entity_id
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_media_gallery ON catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value.value_id = catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.value_id;";
$result = $connection->fetchAll($sql); 

$content[] = ['sku' => __('Sku'),
    'label' => __('Alt Text'),
    'value' => __('Image Path'),
    'image-width' => __('Image Width'),
    'image-height' => __('Image Height'),];

$fileName = 'product_export.csv'; // Add Your CSV File name
$filePath = $directoryList->getPath(DirectoryList::MEDIA) . "/" . $fileName;

foreach ($result as $product){
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize("pub/media/catalog/product/".$product['value']);

    $content[] = [$product['sku'],
    $product['label'],
    $product['value'],
    $width,
    $height,];
    //print_r( $product->getImage()); die;
} 

$csvProcessor->setEnclosure('"')->setDelimiter(',')->saveData($filePath, $content);
$fileFactory->create($fileName, ['type' => "filename",
    'value' => $fileName,
    'rm' => true,
    // True => File will be remove from directory after download.
], DirectoryList::MEDIA, 'text/csv', null);
```